# CFHTTP firewall issue? How are CFHTTP requests made?

Tags: coldfusion

CFHTTP on my new CF 9 server is failing. I get back "408 Request Time-out" when attempting to connect to the test page on the server via its internal or external IP. I am not using SSL and using the standard port 80.

My old CF 9 server can connect to itself fine but it also fails if attempting to connect to the new server.

If I RDP into the server, I am able to pull up the same test page via a web browser or via telnet to that ip port 80.

I suspect that this is a firewall issue. I'd like to know how CF makes an HTTP request under the hood before I talk to the hosting team. What service is making the call? What port is it running under, etc.

Comment: So can you call a page on the server that isn't doing a cfhttp call? If you can, can you cfhttp to a external sites?

Comment: Good question. I just tried and yes, I am able to CFHTTP to an external server. I can pull up pages on the new server just fine that are not doing CFHTTP to itself.

Comment: After more testing, I see that CFHTTP DOES work if I do not include a querystring in the URL. If I put the query string back in the URL it fails. If I use CFHTTPPARAM for the querystring it fails too.

Comment: It turns out the problem is not CFHTTP afterall. The timeout was occuring because the actual page is returning slow and it ran over my defined 10 sec timeout in the CFHTTP call. The querystring was the clue since setting the querystring causes this page to refresh its cache from the DB, which is fast on the other server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what operating system you are running under, but if it is Windows, I'd take a look at the Windows Firewall settings on your new machine, and disable the firewall. That will allow you to check if indeed it is the Firewall in the way.

If that works you can then try and add a firewall exception for the application, i.e. JRun.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The OS is Win2008. The Windows firewall is off but the servers are behind a HW firewall. Does JRun run under any particular port? It is strange that a browser or a telnet session form the server works but CF (JRun - Java) does not